# Is there any way to develop Silverlight applications on OS X?

Tags: c#, silverlight, macos, mono

While all of my machines are Macs, I actually really enjoy working in .NET. I thought it would be fun to try my hand at writing a Silverlight application. Unfortunately, as near as I can tell, Silverlight is not a part of Mono that actually works on OS X.

Is it possible to develop Silverlight on OS X, or will I need to use a VM? If it's possible, is Mono the only option, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you heard of [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight)?

Taken from the project page:

> Moonlight is an open source
>   implementation of Silverlight
>   (http://silverlight.net), primarily
>   for Linux and other Unix/X11 based
>   operating systems. In September of
>   2007, Microsoft and Novell announced a
>   technical collaboration that includes
>   access to Microsoft's test suites for
>   Silverlight and the distribution of a
>   Media Pack for Linux users that will
>   contain licensed media codecs for
>   video and audio.

According to [go-mono.com](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/), you can use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) to develop for Silverlight/Moonlight on Mac OS X.

Comment: I had not. That looks perfect—and trying to run a Moonlight project from inside MonoDevelop even launches my browser with the real Silverlight plugin, which means I'm not testing against the mock frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably stick with a VM - I use VM's on my mac all the time, and Visual Studio is perfectly usable (obviously that does depend on your mac's spec)...

If you want it all for free, you can use VirtualBox, install windows on there (you can always use an evaluation if you don't own it), and then use Visual Studio Express - this SO question tells you how to set Visual Studio Express up for SL dev... [Developing Silverlight in Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365258/developing-silverlight-in-visual-studio-express)

Answer (score 2):

There was a Silverlight development tool that ran in Eclipse called Eclipse tools for Silverlight. It has a Mac version. It looks a bit stagnant though, so I don't know it's current status.

http://www.eclipse4sl.org/

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop does have moonlight projects built-in, so there shouldn't be any issue.

Also- while this prob doesn't fit your case, I bootcamped my MBP and while it's freaky running Win7 + vStudio on mac hardware, it works quite well.

Answer (score -2):

Silverlight is comptatible for MAC OSX via a separate project, whose name I forget. Microsoft release the source code for silverlight to some people that are working on implementing on other platforms, including MAC

However, this means that it's always at least one version late, so MAC users can have access to silverlight 3, but not 4.

Old Mac that are not intel processors, only have access to silverlight 1.

Look at this page for a compatiblity list.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlight#Silverlight_4

Comment: Not correct.  Silverlight 4 runs on the Mac just fine.  Microsoft created the implementation for Mac.  I think the OP is asking if he can compile Silverlight applications using a Mac.

Comment: @Jacob Exactly: I want to write Silverlight on my Mac. Microsoft's official runtime works just fine for actually running what I've built.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Last I heard it was not, but I am happy to see that I was wrong. This shows how much Microsoft want to push this technology to allow it to work on other platforms.Not surprising since they actually got something real nice there.