# Do I need VS 2010 professional or is Express version enough?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing Silverlight in Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365258/developing-silverlight-in-visual-studio-express)

I would like to learn to develop Silverlight applications. But I am not sure what software I need.

I got Expression Studio 4 Ultimate, I also know I will need Visual Studio. But which version. Is Express version enough for Silverlight apps or do I need Professional version?

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of ["Developing Silverlight in Visual Studio Express?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365258/developing-silverlight-in-visual-studio-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express is absolutely fine as long as you don't need plugins, or the more advanced debugging and testing features that Professional has.

Answer (score 1):

View this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365258/developing-silverlight-in-visual-studio-express).
You need Visual Web Developer + Silverlight Tools an other optional tools.